# Как правильно выравнить компоненты с помощью QFormLayout?

Tags: python, qt

В результате выполнения данного кода:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTextEdit, QFormLayout
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("Программа")

te_en = QTextEdit()
te_ru = QTextEdit()
form = QFormLayout()
form.addRow("&En", te_en)
form.addRow("&Ru", te_ru)
window.setLayout(form)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

я ожидал получить:

[image]

но получилось:
[image]

Как можно добиться результата, показаного на первом рисунке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доброго времени суток!

Сразу вопрос: а Вы уверены что Вам для текстового поля именно QTextEdit нужен?

Я бы предложил использовать QLineEdit, с ним Ваш код изменится примерно так:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTextEdit, QFormLayout
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("Программа")

te_en = QLineEdit(window)
te_ru = QLineEdit(window)
form = QFormLayout(window)
form.addRow("&En", te_en)
form.addRow("&Ru", te_ru)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Сразу предупрежу - работоспособность не проверял (нет под рукой PyQt)